# How to maintain aspect ratio for Ionic cards

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, aspect-ratio

I have a list of cards displayed on my Ionic page and I want them to expand proportionally.
Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<ion-content class="home" padding>
  <ion-card class="event-item"  *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + item.img + ')'}" class="card-thumbnail"></div>
    <ion-card-content> 
      <p [innerHTML]="item.excerpt"></p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**SCSS**

```
.event-item {
  margin: 25px 10px;
}

.card-thumbnail {
  height: 18rem;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-x: 50%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
}
```

I have tried a number of things from which setting `padding-top` to percent value on `<ion-card>` element - this made card resizable as desired, but it made image distorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by distorting you mean it's cutting some of the image off, to keep the image proportions determine the image aspect ratio in percentage. For example 4:3 is 100%:75%.

You would then set padding-bottom to 75%, width to 100%, and remove the fixed height altogether.

```
.card-thumbnail {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/jamesreimer/jkk1vLuz/ for a full example.