# Resize image height within Ion-slide

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a small Ionic app that basically allows users to take photos, view them in the app, and then send them off for processing. On the photo page, the photos a user takes are stored in an array, that is bound to the view. These are displayed in ion-slides, as seen below:

```
<ion-slides style="height: 50vh">
<ion-slide *ngFor="let image of images">
  <ion-card>
    <img (click)="takePhoto()" [src]="image.src" />
  </ion-card>
</ion-slide>
```

This all works fine for portrait mode, but when the user puts the phone into landscape mode, the images are too big to be displayed in their entirety. I've tried fiddling with some css to handle the resizing but have been unsuccessful. Even when managing to resize a container the ion-slides are presented in, the photo display still extends past the edge of the screen. I'm absolutely terrible with CSS, so I'm hopeful that there is a simple solution to this, but so far I've yet to find one.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to maintain the [aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470904/how-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-for-ionic-cards)

Comment: Yes this is true. Basically maintaining the size of the aspect ratio while adjusting the size of the element. Sorry for the delayed response.